# Flash player not working in 14.04 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, flash, 14.04

Clean install of 14.04 LTS. Single OS. Have installed Chrome for linux, updated, removed, reinstalled 14.04 LTS.  No flash.  I have done everything from every site I can find, nothing.
Using Chrome I get a Black Screen. (hardware acceleration is off)

Same with Chromium.....

Firefox attempts to update Flash player, then says I need to update my browser and flash to the newest version. (both are up to date).

Been 4 days and I am at my wits end......any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Chrome and chromium doesnt deliver flash anymore. you have to sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-nonfree

Comment: Yep.  Did it.  No Joy.  There is a major bug with Flash player is 14.04 and no one is talking about it.

Comment: weird. its working fine here. which gfx have you?

Comment: working fine for me too, I think it's related to your hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 29):

**Update: the package pepperflashplugin-nonfree is now deprecated.**

You need to install the `adobe-flashplugin`. Make sure to enable Canonical Partners software source before installing the package. It works for Firefox and Chromium

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Read more about this on:

- Ubuntu official site https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash
- [The official Ubuntu Desktop Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html)

Comment: More information here:   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash

Comment: helped for me with firefox as well.

Comment: I know it is silly but you must restart the browser :).

Comment: starting from 05-2015, it's `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK If you use chromium, you indeed in need to install pepperflashplugin-nonfree, but in case of using Google Chrome for linux, it comes with pepperflash preinstalled.   For example I got  ver 34.0.1847.132 here with pepperflash ver.13.0.0.206 installed. To use it by default you need to go to chrome://plugins/ go to Adobe Flash Player section and select what ver. to use

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be a bug with Pepperflashplugin indeed. (Flashplugin-installer package would not work for Chrome too, only on Firefox)

As a workaround, I suggest using Chrome beta channel. (Currently version: 35.0.1916.69-1) First purge google-chrome-stable and also delete your Chrome config for starting clean.

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

This did the trick for me