# How do I install a Flash player in Chromium?

Tags: 12.04, flash, chromium

I have two web browsers:  Chromium, and Mozilla Firefox. Firefox let see Flash videos but with Chromium, I can not see Flash videos. How may I add Flash playback ability to Chromium?

Comment: For >= 14.04 LTS see http://askubuntu.com/questions/452489/flash-player-not-working-in-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

You can install flash player for Chromium by following the instructions over here:

- First make sure you have enabled Multiverse software repository.
  For that, Open "Software & Updates" and then check the multiverse software repository.
- Then install flash player either from terminal using the commmand **sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install ** or install "Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin" from Software Center

Original source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash

Comment: Can you include some instructions in the answer itself, rather than just linking to them?  Maybe copy the most relevant bit into the answer.