# is there a flash player that works with ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lts

**strong text****strong text**firefox keeps asking me to install a flash player so I can play video but every time I try it says there is no plugin for this I need a flash player if I want to view video so how do I fix this
using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer

Comment: See also [Flash player not working in 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452489/flash-player-not-working-in-14-04-lts).

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome doesn't come up with Flash anymore. So you need to install it(as mentioned in the comment also)

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

It will work with Firefox also.
You can install Adobe Flash Player from software center
[image]

Comment: It won't work on Firefox, unless you do some extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

In **Synaptic Package Manager** or **Ubuntu Software Center** install

> flashplugin-installer

or in **terminal**

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```